# Are exist the built-in Conditional Compilation Symbols in the MS Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I use some COM libraries in my code. Their are depending by the target platform (x86\x64). So I need build my project separately x86 and x64 too. Every time when I switch the target platform (x86\x64) in my project settings, I add or remove manually the "PLATFORM_X86" value also into the "Conditional Compilation Symbols" (the "Build" tab).

```
#if PLATFORM_X86
    customTableStyle.SetTextStyleId(cellStyle_1,
      textStyleId.OldIdPtr.ToInt32());
#else
    customTableStyle.SetTextStyleId(cellStyle_1,
      textStyleId.OldIdPtr.ToInt64());
#endif // #if PLATFORM_X86
```

Can I solve it more "clear", without add\remove the "PLATFORM_X86" manually every time? Are exist the "built-in" symbol which are pointing the current platform? If "yes" what its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create two separated solutions configurations: from within *Build* -> *Configuration Manager* select drop down *Active solution configuration* and select , then you can set *Conditional compilation symbols* in project settings for each of those configuration separately.

Then you can use [`Conditional`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attribute on classess or methods:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void Method()
{

}
```

Here is an example from MSDN:

```
#define DEBUG
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
class Class1 
{
   [Conditional("DEBUG")]
   public static void M() {
      Console.WriteLine("Executed Class1.M");
   }
}
class Class2
{
   public static void Test() {
      Class1.M();
   }
}
```

> This declares `Class1.M` as a conditional method. `Class2`'s `Test` method calls this method. Since the conditional compilation symbol `DEBUG` is defined, if `Class2.Test` is called, it will call `M`. If the symbol `DEBUG` had not been defined, then `Class2.Test` would not call `Class1.M`.

Comment: But how does it help me with the "PLATFORM_X86" problem? I still add\remove it manually...

Comment: It is the response not on my question, sorry.

Comment: @Bush, ok, I've edited my answer, I hope it will help you more now.